# How can I check the state of an uninitialized contract variable?

Tags: solidity, tokens, modifiers

I have something like this:

```
import "./Null.sol"; //ERC20 token

contract WrapperCon {
    Null public nullToken;

}
```

then later on I launch the token in the contract with

```
function launchToken(params) internal {
    nullToken = new Null(params);
}
```

I wanted to make a modifier for another function so it would only be able to run after the token was launched.
I checked what was returned for the variable before and after launching the token. So I get either "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" when the var isn't initialized or the address the token was deployed to. So I tried it like this:

```
modifier tokenLaunched(){
   require(nullToken != 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000);
   _;
}
```

ofc that didn't work because '***operator != not compatible with types contract Null and address***'

What am I missing here, how can I check if the token was deployed yet or not?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, any unitialized variable in Ethereum is set to 0, or 0 equivalents like `address(0)`.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg thank you so much, that worked. I compared the address(nullToken) with address(0). Didn't think of doing that!